# issue parsing shell program through python

Tags: python, shell, tkinter

My function `run_deinterleave()` is meant to copy code from the file `deinterleave.sh` then replace the placeholder (`sra_data`) with a file name which has been input by the user and then run it on the command line.

```
def  run_deinterleave():
   codes = open('Project/CODE/deinterleave.sh')     
   codex = codes.read()
   print(inp_address)
   codex = codex.replace('sra_data', inp_address)
   #is opening this twice creating another pipeline?
   stream = os.popen(codex)
   codes.close()
   
   self.txtarea.insert(END,codex)    
#stuff
```

However, I keep getting this  error:

> /bin/sh: 5: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

The code in `deinterleave.sh` works fine and produces two individual files given an interleaved paired end `sra_file` (an output file from genetic sequencing machines, I think :P)

```
#1deinterleave paired end fastq file 
 paste - - - - - - - - < sra_data \
| tee >(cut -f 1-4 | tr "\t" "\n" > /home/lols/Project/reads-1.fq) \
| cut -f 5-8 | tr "\t" "\n" > /home/lols/Project/reads-2.fq
```

Comment: What is a sample `inp_address`?

Comment: /home/lols/Project/sra_data.fq

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. It may also make much of a difference which shell you're using to run that code, see also the description of the "shell" tag that you applied. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

As the error message shows, the code was interpreted by */bin/sh*; if you executed
`/bin/sh Project/CODE/deinterleave.sh`, you'd get the same error, because the [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) `>(…)` is a Bash extension not understood by */bin/sh*.
Besides, since you don't communicate with the shell code, we don't need pipes at all. So instead of `os.popen` I'd use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module), which allows to specify Bash as the shell.

```
   subprocess.run(codex, shell=True, executable="bash")
```

Answer (score 0):

The absolutely best fix is probably to replace the shell script with native Python code; but without a specification and/or sample input, I don't think we can tell you exactly how to do that.

An immediate and trivial fix is to change `deinterlace` so that it accepts an input file parameter.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
paste - - - - - - - - < "${1-sra_data}" |
tee >(cut -f 1-4 | tr "\t" "\n" > "${2-/home/lols/Project/reads-1.fq}") |
cut -f 5-8 | tr "\t" "\n" > "${3-/home/lols/Project/reads-2.fq}"
```

This refactoring also allows you to specify the names of the output files as the second and third command-line arguments.

Also, a Bash script really should not have a `.sh` extension, so probably take that out.

Explictly naming Bash in the shebang line should solve the error message you got when running Bash code in `sh`; perhaps see also [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

With that, your Python code can be reduced to something like

```py
subprocess.run(
    ['Project/CODE/deinterleave', inp_address],
    # probably a good idea
    check=True)
```

though I don't exactly understand the rest of the surrounding function, so it's not clear how exactly to rewrite it.

I *think* the shell script could be reimplemented something like

```py
with open(inp_address, 'r') as sra_data, open(
    '/home/lols/Project/reads-1.fq', 'w') as first, open(
        '/home/lols/Project/reads-2.fq', 'w') as second:
    for idx in range(4):
        first.write(sra_data.readline())
    for idx in range(4):
        second.write(sra_data.readline())
```